# How to href the elements in a python list with Flask?

Tags: python

How can I transform to different html hrefs the elements of a list?. For instance:

```
A = [string1, string2, ..., stringN]
```

To:

`A = [`[`string1`](https://this_is_url_1/)`,` [`string2`](https://this_is_url_2/)`, ...,` [`stringN`](https://this_is_url_N/)`]`

Comment: A normal plain text file OR python code does not support HTML Link

Answer (score 1):

```
strings = ['the','quick','brown','fox']

result = ['<a href="http://this_is_url_{}">{}</a>'.format(a,a) for a in strings]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!, I forgot to mention that the links must be different, for each element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear and ambiguous.

If string is hyperlink..

```
A = [string1, string2, ..., stringN]
```

`hrefs = ['<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (a,a) in A]`